# How can I dismiss `custominfoviewcontroller` programatically on tvOS?

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

On tvOS 11.0+, `custominfoviewcontroller` is added to `AVPlayerViewController`. My question is how to dismiss the whole info panel after selecting something in my custom info view controller?

I tried to use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`. Although it does dismiss the info panel, the info panel doesn't reveal again after I try to swipe down immediately.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? I'm having the same challenge right now.

Comment: No unfortunately 

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `PlayerCustomInfoViewController` to you player's customInfoViewController
Some thing like

`` // If you have created a `MainViewController` as a subclass of `AVPlayerViewController` 
self.customInfoViewController = PlayerCustomInfoViewController(initalize parameter).. ``

And once u selected the required info on your `PlayerCustomInfoViewController` then you need get the call back to the controller where you have implemented your player(MainViewController).
Then from there you dismiss the `customInfoViewController.dismiss()`

I tried the same and its working fine.